# jQuery permanently change value of DIV/Span

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently learning jQuery and I would like to know how can I permanently change the value of a span or div, so anybody that revisits my page will see the updated value and not the one initially set in my HTML.

The event that has to change the value is a click on a button.

jQuery code:

```
    $("#add").click( function() {
     var counter = parseInt($("#hiddenVal").val());
     counter++;
     $("#hiddenVal").val(counter);
     $("#theCount").text(counter);    
     });
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenVal" value ="0"/>
<button id="add">Add +1</button>
<div id="theCount"></div>
```

So, I would like to use the hidden input to store the value and the "theCount" div to show it. I want it to permanently change whenever somebody clicks on the add button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `permanently change` means what ?

Comment: You will have to consider using cookies or storing it on the server else it will be lost between visits.

Comment: You need to store updated value to server side and when page load take value from server side and display.

Comment: Well, I want the value to change and remain the changed value. Let's say if somebody clicks the button, the value should change to value+1 and stay like that, so when anybody else enters the website, he will see the changed value.

Comment: You will have to store it somewhere on the server then.

Comment: @ketan, How could I achieve that using jQuery?

Comment: You could use AJAX, its more efficient than posting the whole page back

Comment: @trooper as per my knowledge only using JQuery not possible you should submit your changes to server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you will need to do a lot more work. Firstly, you need to be able to submit the changed value back to the server, using a JQuery AJAX post.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Try something along these lines...

```
  $.post( "url of your server side method",
         { value: $("#hiddenVal").val() } );
```

This will require some server side code that is able to handle the post from the javascript in your web page. Within this server side code you will need to save the updated value somewhere, typically in a database .

Finally, you need to build up your page on each request from the updated value from the database.

Essentially, what I have described is a dynamically data driven website. Most significant website project templates for Visual Studio have examples of how to do this. If you are not using the .NET stack, I am sure that whatever technology that you are using will have similar examples.

Also, you wouldn't need to store the hidden value...

```
$("#add").click( function() {
     var counter = parseInt($("#hiddenVal").val());
     counter++;
     $("#hiddenVal").val(counter);
     $("#theCount").text(counter);    
 });
```

becomes

```
$("#add").click( function() {
     $("#theCount").text(parseInt($("#theCount").text())++);   
     $.post( "url of your server side method",
         { value: $("#theCount").text() } );
 });
```

Good luck